# Sort list dynamically on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, ordering

There is a list of numbers in column A in an Excel worksheet. I would like to display these numbers in column C *in order*.

Column C should update automatically when column A is modified, without needing to manually reorder anything.

Comment: I dont think this is possible in Excel, at least not without using a Macro. Filtering is always done manually.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose It definitely *is* possible ;-) See my answer.

Comment: @robinCTS thanks :) Learn something new everyday. Nice solution!

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose If you haven't done so yet, check out the even *better* solution, courtesy of AFH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to [AFH](//superuser.com/users/327367), the formula can be simplified to just the `SMALL()` function!

---

This can be done with a very simple normal formula in a Table:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

The formula in `C2:C8` is:

```dart
=SMALL(A:A,ROW()-ROW($1:$1))
```

A Table is required so that entering a value just below the bottom of the table, i.e. in `A9`, will cause the formula in column `C` to be extended downwards.

The Table can be dispensed with if only existing data will be modified, or if you are comfortable extending the formula by hand, or if you are prepared to pre-fill it past the current end of the data.

Comment: Nice answer, but I found that `=IFERROR(SMALL(A:A,ROW()-1),"")` works equally well. What's the advantage of adding `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`? And `ROW($1:$1)` always returns 1, so why not use the literal, which can be incremented if there are more header lines?

Comment: @AFH Good catch!. There's no need for the `INDEX()`/`MATCH()` at all and there's no advantage to having them. (I'm so used to more complex formula where they *are* required, that I forgot that for this simple case they weren't needed.) The reason for using `ROW($1:$1)` is *precisely* so that if more header rows are added (or rows inserted above the Table) **after** the formula has been entered, the Table won't break and you *don't* need to adjust a literal value to fix it. It makes the Table pretty much bullet-proof. I've updated the answer with an even simpler version. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78829/discussion-between-robincts-and-afh).